# Flutter build multiple Cards

Tags: json, wordpress, flutter

I have a Function postList that retrieves a list of posts from a json produced by Wordpress. The id variable is the page number, so each time I arrive to the bottom it adds a Circular progress bar and loads more values as a Card (customCard function).

```
_getJsonData(url, page) async {
  final response = await http.get("$url?page=$page");
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    return json.decode(response.body);
  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an
     error. throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
}

customCard(value) {
  return  new Card(
    child: new Text ("Post ID: $value"),
  );
}

postsList(url, int id) {
  //List cards;
  _getJsonData(url, id).then((val) {
    for (var singlePost in val) {
      String myID = singlePost["id"].toString();
      print ("Post ID: $myID");

      customCard(myID);
    }
  });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Infinite Posts List"),
    ),
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: items.length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index == items.length) {
          return _buildProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          return Container(
            child: postsList(postsUrl, index+1),
          );
        }
      },
      controller: _scrollController,
    ),
  );
}
```

Here the console result:

```
Initializing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Reloaded 1 of 507 libraries in 990ms.
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169266
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169169
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169065
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169136
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169093
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 150806
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 168330
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169125
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 168756
I/flutter (13984): Post ID: 169028
```

It works and prints on the console the 10 posts I have per page, but the problem is that the output is an empty Container. Like it never produces the customCard.

Don't know if I am being clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in the postsList function. Modify your functions as such:

```
Widget customCard(value) {
  return  new Card(
    child: new Text ("Post ID: $value"),
  );
}

Widget postsList(url, int id) {
  //List cards;
  List<Widget> list = [];
  _getJsonData(url, id).then((val) {
    for (var singlePost in val) {
      String myID = singlePost["id"].toString();
      print ("Post ID: $myID");

      list.add(customCard(myID));
    }
    return Column(
      children: list,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Still blank. I tested with a return inside postsList but outside _getJsonData and it shows the return. So I tried returning the list... Nothing. list.lenght outside _getJsonData is null

Comment: @RaffaeleColleo could you show me the _getJsonData function as well? There might be something wrong there

Comment: _getJsonData(url, page) async {
    final response = await http.get("$url?page=$page");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
      throw Exception('Failed to load post');
    }
  }